# Performance counters not showing up in AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm having issues with getting performance counters to show up in Aws CloudWatch. I followed the steps [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441225/how-to-monitor-free-disk-space-at-aws-ec2-with-cloud-watch-in-windows/49293900#49293900) and below is CloudWatch json file.
Anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

```html
{
  "IsEnabled": true,
  "EngineConfiguration": {
    "Components": [
      {
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Id": "PerformanceCounterMemory",
        "Parameters": {
          "CategoryName": "Memory",
          "CounterName": "Available MBytes",
          "DimensionName": "",
          "DimensionValue": "",
          "InstanceName": "",
          "MetricName": "Memory",
          "Unit": "Megabytes"
        }
      },
      {
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Id": "PerformanceCounterDisk",
        "Parameters": {
          "CategoryName": "LogicalDisk",
          "CounterName": "% Free Space",
          "DimensionName": "InstanceId",
          "DimensionValue": "{instance_id}",
          "InstanceName": "C:",
          "MetricName": "FreeDiskPercentage",
          "Unit": "Percent"
        }
      },
      {
  "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
  "Id": "CloudWatch",
  "Parameters": {
   "AccessKey": "",
   "NameSpace": "PerformanceMonitor",
   "Region": "us-west-2a",
   "SecretKey": ""
  }
      }
    ],
    "Flows": {
      "Flows": [
       "(PerformanceCounterMemory,PerformanceCounterDisk),CloudWatch"
      ]
    },
    "PollInterval": "00:00:15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the NameSpace parameter on your CloudWatchLogs component.

This is what mine looks like:

```
{
    "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
    "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
    "Parameters": {
        "NameSpace": "PerformanceMonitor",
        "Region": "eu-west-1"
    }
}
```

Comment: MisterSmith, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: @kennyT - the namespace line is the only difference I can see between your config and mine. Could be a permissions issue?